# Robertson-Seymour fails for topological minor ordering? (I.e., subgraphs and subdivision)

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, order-theory

The Robertson-Seymour theorem says that the set of isomorphism classes of finite graphs, with the minor ordering ($G \le H$ if $G$ is a [minor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $H$) is a well partial ordering (it is well-founded and has no infinite antichains).

Wikipedia [currently](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Graph_minor&oldid=531666627#Topological_minors) says that if we replace the minor ordering by the "topological minor" ordering -- that is, $G\le H$ if some [subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_%28graph_theory%29) of $G$ can be embedded in $H$ -- then this is no longer a well partial order.

Unfortunately it gives no citation for this so I was hoping someone could either point me to a counterexample or come up with one.  (Or tell me that in fact it's wrong, or that the problem is still open, etc.)

Obviously, this order is still well-founded, so a counterexample would have to take the form of an infinite antichain.  (Well, or some other way of showing that something's not a wpo.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that an example of an infinite canonical antichain is constructed in [this paper,](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895696900027) in which it is proved that a minor closed class of graphs $\mathcal{G}$ is quasi-well-ordered by the topological minor relation if and only if some $B_n$ is not in $\mathcal{G}$, where $B_n$ is the path obtained from doubling each edge in an $(n+1)$-path.

*EDIT:* Here is the antichain construction:

[image: Antichain double circles]
[image: Antichain double paths]

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I'll upvote/accept/award this as soon as I get a chance to verify the antichain for myself.  Note, by the way, that the antichain given in the paper is not $B_n$ (because in fact this is a chain -- each is a subgraph of the next), but rather what it calls $A_n$; $A_n$ is $B_{n-1}$, but with the two end vertices each having two self-loops in addition.  (And I'm guessing by subdividing you could probably make an antichain of simple graphs too?)

Comment: Having checked this I can say that yes, by subdividing you can thereby also get an antichain of simple graphs.  Thanks again!

Comment: @HarryAltman Would you mind elaborating on how to obtain an antichain by subdivision? If say you take the antichain $(A_n)_n$ where $A_n:=$ the edge-repeated n-path with loops on the two ends (as Fig 2 in [Excluding a Long Double Path Minor](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895696900027)), subdivide each $A_n$ into a simple graph $A'_n$, it is not obvious why $(A'_n)_n$ remains an antichain.

Comment: I just meant taking a doubled paths and subdividing them to obtain simple graphs.  This is an antichain because, e.g., the number of vertices of degree 4 is different in each one, and subdivision can't change that.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, @HarryAltman. I still fail to see why $A_n\not\preceq A_m$ implies $A'_n\not\preceq A'_m$ for each $n<m$ though, where $A'_n$ is a subdivision of $A_n$ into simple graph. We seem to need $A_n\preceq A'_n$ and $A'_m\preceq A_m$ for the implication above to hold, but we only have $A_n\preceq A'_n$.

Comment: Here $A \preceq B $ means $A$ is a topological minor of $B$. Now I know what you meant. Though downstairs we can contract those one end of degree 2, eventually we get back the repeated edges, so no two vertices are really "collapsable".

Comment: Just look at the simple graphs directly.  Don't bother trying to infer it from the non-simple versions.