# Why converting a minor of a graph into a subdivision is not always possible?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In my attempt to try to understand the Kuratowski's Theorem and the Wagner's Theorem, I encountered an article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem)  where it is mentioned that converting a minor of a graph into a subdivision of the same type is not always possible.

I tried to look somewhere else but there is no example of a case where converting a minor into a subdivision of the same type is not possible.

Could somebody please give any example? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160022/graph-theory-minors-vs-topological-minors/1160040#1160040