# Topological Minors on Simple Graphs --- Antichains?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

This is a follow-up discussion on [@296991](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296991/robertson-seymour-fails-for-topological-minor-ordering-i-e-subgraphs-and-sub), with further questions.

In the following discussion, "graphs" are finite but not necessarily simple (i.e. $|V(G)|<\infty,$ but allow loops and repeated edges). $H$ is a topological minor of $G$ ($H\preceq_{\textrm{topo.minor}}G$) if $H$ is a subdivision of a subgraph of $G$. A well quasi-order is a quasi-order without infinite antichain, i.e. $\nexists \{a_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ s.t. $\forall n<m$, $a_n\not\preceq a_m$.

It is known that the topological minor order is not a well quasi order on graphs, witnessed by e.g. the antichain  [$\underline{\{A_n\}_n}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXra8.png) (from [**Excluding a long double path minor**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jctb.1996.0002)). Theorem 3.4 of the same paper proved that if $\mathscr{G}$ is a minor-closed class of graphs, then $(\mathscr{G},\preceq_{\textrm{topo.minor}})$ is a well-quasi-order iff $\mathscr{G}$ contains finitely many $A_n$'s. However the class of simple graphs is not minor-closed: contracting an edge in a triangle gives a non-simple path.

It was claimed in @Harry Altman's comment on [@269961](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296991/robertson-seymour-fails-for-topological-minor-ordering-i-e-subgraphs-and-sub) that by subdivision, one may find **a $\preceq_{\textrm{topo.minor}}$-antichain** in the class of **simple graphs** as well. I wonder how this is achieved: in particular, if we subdivide e.g. each $A_n$ into a simple graph $A'_n$, it is not obvious to me that $A_n\not\preceq_{\textrm{topo.minor}} A_m\implies A'_n\not\preceq_{\textrm{topo.minor}} A'_m$.

Moreover, if subdivision does not work, are there any **good sources proving or disproving the well-quasi-orderedness of (simple graphs, $\preceq_{\textrm{topo.minor}}$)**?

Thank you.

Comment: Just gained enough "reputation" to comment. Will update the post once it's answered either [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296991/robertson-seymour-fails-for-topological-minor-ordering-i-e-subgraphs-and-sub?noredirect=1&lq=1) or here.